# Is there no conjugation needed in this specific sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

Today I read this sentence somewhere on stackexchange.com (I don't add a source because I don't want to blame anybody):

> The [...] postulate [..] is that there is no experiment that **determine** the state of motion of any inertial frame relative to the outside world [...].

Initially I thought that it shall be "*determines*" instead but I'm uncertain since it got written by a native English speaker.

Who's right?

Comment: Somehow I _knew_ the source before checking - I had just clicked that question open in another tab from the hot network questions. But there is little reason to assume this is anything but a typo for _to determine_, _that determines_ or _that can determine_.

Comment: In the same answer that you quote from, the author also writes "The speed of light is _the_ measured to be the same in all inertial reference frames". That _the_ does not belong there, either. So indeed I think it's safe to assume typos or honest mistakes, rather than obscure but correct use of English :)

Comment: Unless you want to sound jarringly dialectal, use *was written,* not *got written.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a typographical error.

You are right in that it should be *determines*, although *can determine* would also be acceptable.

The sentence as written could be an error for either possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The noun & verb should agree in number, singular or plural. The person that posted the statement should have proofread & edited before clicking the Post button. That would be a good practice for anyone posting to any site.

Comment: Is it really about the number?

Comment: @Conclusio I'm not sure about your use of the indefinite pronoun, it. If you mean the topic, no. The content is what's important. If you mean the grammar, yes. According to [The Blue Book of Grammar](http://grammar.com), a singular subject takes a singular verb, whereas a plural subject takes a plural verb.

Answer (score 0):

In English grammar, "number" is just a term used to indicate singular vs. plural, typically for the purposes of subject-verb agreement.  It doesn't have anything to do with numbers like five or twenty. If someone asks, "Do the subject and verb agree in number?" then they are asking if a singular noun has a verb conjugated in the singular, or if a plural noun has a verb conjugated in the plural.

Don't be confused by the fact that most **plural nouns** end with "-s" and most **verbs conjugated for the singular** end with "-s."  This is just a coincidence -- the "-s" conjugation on a verb has nothing do with the "-s" that makes most nouns plural.  The verb "walks" is not a "plural" verb because verbs can't be singular or plural (that designation is for nouns/pronouns).  The verb "walks" is conjugated for a third-person singular subject, as in "He walks to school every day."  When it is conjugated for a plural subject, the verb is "walk," as in "They walk to school every day."